# reducing repetitive tasks in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I notice that i am doing the same thing multiple time, just with slightly different values:

```
HCCtreshold <- 40000

  claimsMonthly[, HCC12mnth := +(HCCtreshold < claim12month)][ HCC12mnth == 1, `:=` (aboveHCCth12mnth = (claim12month - HCCtreshold))][is.na(aboveHCCth12mnth),aboveHCCth12mnth := 0]
  claimsMonthly[, HCC11mnth := +(HCCtreshold < claim11month)][ HCC11mnth == 1, `:=` (aboveHCCth11mnth = (claim11month - HCCtreshold))][is.na(aboveHCCth11mnth),aboveHCCth11mnth := 0]
  claimsMonthly[, HCC10mnth := +(HCCtreshold < claim10month)][ HCC10mnth == 1, `:=` (aboveHCCth10mnth = (claim10month - HCCtreshold))][is.na(aboveHCCth10mnth),aboveHCCth10mnth := 0]
```

So started with something like this:

```
  k <- seq.default(from = 8, to = 12, by = 1)
  claimsMonthly[paste0("HCC", k, "mnth") := lapply(k, function(x) (+(HCCtreshold < paste0("HCC", k, "mnth"))))]
```

i get an error:

```
Error: Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

I also tried:

```
 for(k in 8:12){
    claimsMonthly[, paste0("HCC", k, "mnth") := +(HCCtreshold < paste0("HCC", k, "mnth"))]
  }
```

the columns are created correctly, but i get incorrect values inside them. I get an `1` everywhere

I am not sure what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Would help if you provided reproducible data. And it wouldn't hurt if you fixed your indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer some suggestions and, with some fake data, try them out.

1. You can programmatically define names on the left-hand side of `:=` if you wrap a vector in `c(...)`, so for instance `DT[ c(vec_of_names) := list(some, values)]`.
2. You can programmatically retrieve values of variables with a vector of variable names and `mget`. While I generally think `mget` can indicate problematic code, I believe that in here it works with low risk. (While `mget` and `get` normally retrieve variables from the operating environment, often `.GlobalEnv`, from within a `data.table` operation then retrieve columns just as easily.)
3. Instead of a double-tap of assignment with `== 1` and then `is.na(...)`, we can use some logical trickery and the `data.table::fcoalesce` function. (If you aren't familiar, `fcoalesce` operates like SQL's coalesce function which is a vector-friendly way of finding the first non-`NA` value in arguments of vectors.

   ```r
   fcoalesce(c(1, 2, NA, NA), c(11, 12, 13, NA), c(21, 22, 23, 24))
   # [1]  1  2 13 24
   ```

   We can use `fcoalesce(some + math * calc, 0)` to do the math and, if `NA`, replace it with `0`. (We use it on the `above*` variables below, and not necessarily on the `HCC*` logical variables. It can apply there too, if desired. If those `HCC*` variables are throw-away, though, it just doesn't matter.)

Fake data:

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
hccthreshold <- 50
dat <- data.table( claim10month = sample(99, 10), claim11month = sample(99, 10), claim12month = sample(99, 10) )
dat$claim11month[5] <- NA
dat
#     claim10month claim11month claim12month
#  1:           91           46           90
#  2:           92           71           14
#  3:           28           91           96
#  4:           80           25           91
#  5:           61           NA            8
#  6:           49           89           49
#  7:           69           97           37
#  8:           13           11           84
#  9:           60           95           41
# 10:           64           51           76
```

First, let's programmatically determine the column names we want to act on, and from then create the same vectors for the new variables. (I'm a big fan of determining and adapting these variable names programmatically, so that if you get a partial data set your code still works. You might consider setting checks and alarms to catch something wrong. For instance, `stopifnot(length(claimnames) == 12L)`, in case you are expecting to always have precisely 12 months.)

```r
claimnames <- grep("^claim[0-9]+month", colnames(dat), value = TRUE)
hccnames <- gsub("^claim", "HCC", claimnames)
abovenames <- gsub("^claim", "aboveHCC", claimnames)
claimnames
# [1] "claim10month" "claim11month" "claim12month"
hccnames
# [1] "HCC10month" "HCC11month" "HCC12month"
abovenames
# [1] "aboveHCC10month" "aboveHCC11month" "aboveHCC12month"
```

And now, we can process the data.

```r
dat[, c(hccnames) := lapply(mget(claimnames), `>`, hccthreshold) ]
dat[, c(abovenames) := Map(function(hcc, clm) fcoalesce(clm - hcc * hccthreshold, 0),
                           mget(hccnames), mget(claimnames)) ]
dat
#     claim10month claim11month claim12month HCC10month HCC11month HCC12month aboveHCC10month aboveHCC11month aboveHCC12month
#  1:           91           46           90       TRUE      FALSE       TRUE              41              46              40
#  2:           92           71           14       TRUE       TRUE      FALSE              42              21              14
#  3:           28           91           96      FALSE       TRUE       TRUE              28              41              46
#  4:           80           25           91       TRUE      FALSE       TRUE              30              25              41
#  5:           61           NA            8       TRUE         NA      FALSE              11               0               8
#  6:           49           89           49      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE              49              39              49
#  7:           69           97           37       TRUE       TRUE      FALSE              19              47              37
#  8:           13           11           84      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE              13              11              34
#  9:           60           95           41       TRUE       TRUE      FALSE              10              45              41
# 10:           64           51           76       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE              14               1              26
```

I chose to keep the `HCC*` variables as `logical` instead of your `+(...)` integers, but it's directly translatable and up to you.

Comment: i indeed need integers instead of logical variables, as i am summing up the columns later on. However i struggle how to do that translation. I am not familiar with '>' inside the lapply function, nor the mget function (there are suprisingly little example for that, so i guess i am missing something trivial). How can i get integers instead of logicals within the data.table?

Comment: `mget` takes a *list* of variables names and returns a named `list` of their values, see `aa <- 1; bb <- 2; mget(c("aa","bb"))`, that's about it. As for `\`>\``, that's equivalent to `dat[, c(hccnames) := lapply(mget(claimnames), function(a) (a > hccthreshold)) ]`. If you need them to be integers instead of logicals, instead use `dat[, c(hccnames) := lapply(mget(claimnames), function(a) +(a > hccthreshold)) ]` (just adding the `+` to convert lgl to int, it's a nice shortcut).

Comment: aaah ok, `>` is a neat shortcut! I have been trying to extend this solution. The data has columns "ID"  and "YEAR" and i wanted to check if for some "ID" there is a 1 in "HCC" for consecutive years? This wont be possible with lapply I assume?

Comment: It sounds like you need `lapply` to work on more than one vector at a time, is that right? Look into `Map`, where `lapply(vec, function(a) sum(a))` is the same as `Map(function(a) sum(a), vec)`, but one can also do `Map(function(a,b) a-b, vec1, vec2)`, and it "zips" them together.

Comment: yes exactly... i am basically struggeling with translateting the data.table by clause into lapply. I will have a look at the map for sure. You answers have been very helpful in this ,for me, uncharted territory